# Facebook JS SDK FB.Login function

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

In my website, I have a button for "facebook connect", which when clicked on, triggers the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log(<?=(isLoggedIn()+0)?>);
    $("#fbconnect").click( function(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response.authResponse));
       if (response.authResponse) {
        window.location = window.location;
         alert('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
       } else {
         alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
     }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});         
                  } );
    });
    </script>
```

The button works well: it shows the facebook login dialog, and then alerts the appropriate message. However, when I refresh the page, the user is still logged out both server-side and client-side. Do I need to handle the access token and cookies myself or does the javascript SDK take care of that? If the latter, then why doesn't this code work?

Thank you.

UPDATE 1:
It works perfectly on localhost with Firefox, and on the server with all browsers. So the problem exists only for chrome and on localhost. Is there some chrome security setting that prevents cookies from being saved for localhost?

Comment: Did you initialize the SDK with the cookie option set to true?

Comment: `window.location = window.location;` Is this supposed to be like this?

Comment: @DrColossos I did that to refresh the page after getting a response from facebook. worked but didn't have any effect on the problem I mentioned.

Comment: @user1233296 You should use `window.location.reload()` then.

Comment: @DrColossos Thanks, but as I said, that's not the problem. The problem is that the facebook login function doesn't work as expected in chrome.

Comment: @user1233296 I know, it's jsut an improvement.